# Encountered the symbol end of file error while Pl/SQL execution

Tags: oracle, plsql, liquibase

[PL/SQL with Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5r2Y.png)

I am running a very simple `Declare begin end statement` but it's throwing the above error. Even though the pl/sql works perfectly if I run it in sql developer. But when I put it inside my liquibase project it gives the error `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" ..`

I tried removing the last semicolon and putting a slash / at the end. But the error still remains. I am not sure if there is something in liquibase settings that needs to be done to run the `declare begin blocks`

**Things tried:**
I tried putting NULL and still the same error.
[null inside begin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCHsc.png)

Error with empty Declare:
[empty declare block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKkId.png)

**The following worked:

<sqlFile endDelimiter="/"**

Comment: I'm not familiar with liquibase, but oracle doesn't allow empty blocks. Try to add `NULL;` into your `BEGIN ... END;`

Comment: @markalex I updated the script but it still has the same error. For some reason, it always gives an error on line 2.

Comment: Please stop putting screenshots into your question: [it's a bad idea](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: ok. Will put the code from next time

Comment: @markalex I got it working by specifying the endDelimiter as /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's throwing the error because there is nothing between `BEGIN` and `END`. In a pl/sql block, that is where the magic happens. A statement is expected between BEGIN and END. If you really want nothing to happen (like you:  you're going to finish your code later and you just want to check if it runs with what you have in the DECLARE section) then you can use the pl/sql statement that does nothing: `NULL;`.
Try the following:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN 
  NULL;
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

A good place to start is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/block.html#GUID-9ACEB9ED-567E-4E1A-A16A-B8B35214FC9D).

Comment: I updated the script but it still has the same error. For some reason, it always gives an error on line 2.  There is a variable declaration between the Declare and begin statements. I did try to add or remove some lines. But still the same error. I have attached the latest pic in the OP. Do let me know what you think we can try experimenting to understand the root cause of the error. Have added one more pic with an empty declare block, not sure if that will give some clue. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Koean I got it working by specifying the endDelimiter as / in the liquibase XML. Thanks a lot, discussing with you guys gets me focused and resolves a lot of my queries.

Comment: Ah yes, liquibase is very picky about that. For normal dml you can use both ";" and "/" but pl/sql statements always have to end with a "/"